# Checking if a set is a subset of another in a functional implementation

Tags: functional-programming, set, scheme

If you are representing sets by their characteristic functions, such that a set is a function that takes in an element and returns true if the element is a member of a set, how would you check that a set is a subset of another without trying every element in the universe (usually impossible)?

Here is a representation of this kind of set in Scheme. I want to define the function (subset? set1 set2).

```sche
(define EMPTY-SET (lambda (x) #f))

(define (set-contains? maybe-elem set)
  (set maybe-elem))
 
(define (set-add to-add set)
  (lambda (x) (or (equal? x to-add) (set x))))
 
(define (list->set l)
  (foldr set-add EMPTY-SET l))
 
(define (intersect set1 set2)
  (lambda (x) (and (set-contains? x set1) (set-contains? x set2))))

; examples:
(define ex-set-1 (list->set (list 1 2 3 4)))
(define ex-set-2 (list->set (list 3 4 5 6)))

(display (set-contains? 2 (intersect ex-set-1 ex-set-2))) ; false
(display (set-contains? 3 (intersect ex-set-1 ex-set-2))) ; true
```

Comment: For this, the modern software uses binary decision diagrams for encoding sets.

I do provide details here about how you can encode the characteristic functions using BDD, as you can find alone. I also posted a few times answers on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the set interface you have defined. You need to have some way to list the members of the first set, in order to query the second set for each of them. In some cases you could query the entire universe, as you suggest; or you could add to the set interface with message-passing, so that for example

```
(set 'contains? x)
```

answers the original question, and

```
(set 'list)
```

returns a list of all its members.